# Element with background inside DIV with rounded corners bleeding out

Tags: html, css

I'm banging my head against the HTML/CSS wall. I am trying to put a colored title at the top of a DIV with rounded corners. The background of the title bleeds out of the bounds of the rounded corners of the containing DIV.

I've tried applying a `background-clip:padding-box` to both the `DIV` and the `H1`'s style with no effect. I've tried applying a `border-radius` to the `H1`, but since the height is different, the corners don't line up for the desired effect.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rounded Edges With Background</title>
    <style>
      body,
      html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .outer_box {
        width: 500px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 25px;
      }

      .title {
        width: 100%;
        background: #00f;
        color: #fff;
        margin-top:0;
        background-clip: padding-box;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer_box">
      <h1 class="title">Here's a title</h1>
      <p>Here's some content.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(also in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisbw/7rb25w38/1/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this code, is this waht are you looking for ?

the `overflow: hidden` hides whatever passes the `.outer_box` borders

and `padding: 10px;` just to makes it look nice.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rounded Edges With Background</title>
    <style>
      body,
      html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .outer_box {
        width: 500px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 25px;

        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .title {
        width: 100%;
        background: #00f;
        color: #fff;
        margin-top:0;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer_box">
      <h1 class="title">Here's a title</h1>
      <p>Here's some content.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! the `overflow` is what I was missing. (and this is just a repro of what I'm seeing in my actual code, hence it's lack of prettiness)

Answer (score 1):

you should add the property

```
overflow:hidden
```

to the outer_box. Basically what it does is it hides whatever is past the border. You should also add some padding to the title.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the `h1` tag inside the `outer_box` rounded border to.

```
.outer_box h1 {
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
```